# Reducing a list by intersecting the first and last common characters

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an initial list as follows:

`ab, aj, ad, ae, bd, bc, bd, bg, bj, dj`

The algorithm should intersect the first and last common characters of the elements in this list to form

`abd, abj, bdj`

and finally (as the result)

`abdj`

which is the longest intersection.

Any suggestions on an algorithm to get this ?

Comment: You can treat strings (`ab`,...,`dj`) as graph's nodes, and add arcs between nodes that ends and starts with the same char (`ab->bd`, `ad->dj` etc.) and then look for the longest path in a DAG. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple graph search would do. Here's a solution, no fancy stuff (cyclic checks, caching paths) though. You should add these for optimal performance. Note that this is a full graph search with all its weaknesses (i.e. combinatorial explosion, NP, etc.)

```
static List<string> _graph = new List<string>() { "ab", "aj", "ad", "ae", "bd", "bc", "bd", "bg", "bj", "dj" };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string longest = string.Empty; // Result will be here.
    foreach (string node in _graph)
        GenerateChildren(node,ref longest);
}

static void GenerateChildren(string parent, ref string longest)
{
    // Store longest path.
    if (parent.Length > longest.Length)
        longest = parent;
    foreach (string child in _graph.Where(child=>parent.EndsWith(child.Substring(0,1))))
        GenerateChildren(parent+child.Substring(1),ref longest);
}
```